# Grid Generation error

Tags: matlab

I have worked out one sample code for grid analysis.
But each time I am having an error.
Here is my error and my code.

I think am using the function in matlab wrongly. Can anyone please guide me on how to run the function in matlab?

Comment: This question is very vague, consider adding more details to assist others in assisting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the function some input

```
 Analyse_Grid("put something here (wf value)")
```

Comment: is it possible for me to send you the complete file to verify? The fact is that i have 5 functions but i need to use the GA toolbox in Matlab to run them.

Comment: @Ellie , I am no expert in GA, however, it seems like you need to understand your problem properly. From last few discussions, I felt that you do not understand and formulate your problem by yourself, but rather taking a ready pieces of codes (correct me if I am wrong). And that is ok in some cases but you have to spend effort to understand what is the work between your hand to be able to develop it. Others can help you in solving some issues, but you are the expert who is supposed to understand your system and at least detect where is the problem.

Comment: I have worked out many many tutorials online. And I am trying to piece some of them together, hence the case i formulated in the other question.  I think for the GA codes am okay with it, but not the ga toolbox, but over all am having a lot of issues with making my scripts work. you are absolutely right, I am not formulating my issue well.. Oh gosh. .this is too confusing.